# Pivot Grid Error?

Tags: asp.net

I'm just starting out with the ASPxPivotGrid, and I found that setting all the fields from my cube using the design view causes the control to display the error above (though curiously if i set it up using a SQL source, it works fine). 
I then setup the control using the source view which worked.  I set the OLAPConnectionString property in the source view too.

Then, getting it to behave how I need it to brought the real problems :
I have the control inside an UpdatePanel, and dont want it to be visible on page load.
What is the best way to add the control after a button is clicked?
I had originally set Visible="false" in the source view but this led to the javascript not being loaded (so the trial version watermark wasn't even on the page).

I discovered that not setting the OLAPConnectionString property allowed the control to be rendered, but not databound; so responding to the button click, i set the OLAPConnectionString and call databind, and get the error above again.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Confirm that you are using the correct version of OLEDB dataprovider..........